# Оптимизировать и минимизировать несколько SQL запросов

Tags: php, sql

**Как оптимизировать и минимизировать эти четыре запроса в один?**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `pivot` SET `curse` = '{$close}', `time`='{$timestamp}' WHERE `pair`='{$pairs[$i]}' AND `type`='close' AND `time`='{$timestamp_old}';") or die("...");

mysql_query("UPDATE `pivot` SET `curse` = '{$open}', `time`='{$timestamp}' WHERE `pair`='{$pairs[$i]}' AND `type`='open' AND `time`='{$timestamp_old}';") or die("...");

mysql_query("UPDATE `pivot` SET `curse` = '{$min}', `time`='{$timestamp}' WHERE `pair`='{$pairs[$i]}' AND `type`='min' AND `time`='{$timestamp_old}';") or die("...");

mysql_query("UPDATE `pivot` SET `curse` = '{$max}', `time`='{$timestamp}' WHERE `pair`='{$pairs[$i]}' AND `type`='max' AND `time`='{$timestamp_old}';") or die("...");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `pivot` SET `curse` = case `type` when 'close' then '{$close}'
when 'min' then '{$min}' when 'open' then '{$open}' when 'max' then '{$max}' end 
, `time`='{$timestamp}' WHERE `pair`='{$pairs[$i]}' and `type` in ('close', 'min', 'open','max') AND `time`='{$timestamp_old}';") or die("...");
```

Comment: Обращайтесь.

Comment: Попробовал выполнить: http://pastebin.com/DSz99xN6

Затронуто строк: 4. ( запрос занял 8.1943 сек. )

Как можно еще оптимизировать?

Мне нужно каждую секунду выполнять такой запрос, для каждой валюты, всего их 17, значит 17 таких запросов в секунду.

Comment: Время нереальное. Сколько у вас записей в таблице?
Постройте индексы на столбцах, по которым выполняется отбор.

Comment: @msi, 5875200 записей. :D   (Скрин: http://vk.cc/3r01MH)

Мне нужно, чтобы для всех валютных пар (их 17) был записан курс (открытие,закрытие,максимум,минимум) по состоянию на каждую секунду в течении одного дня.

Comment: Добавил индексы: http://vk.cc/3r2glA Правильно, нет?

Результат: http://vk.cc/3r2gIb

Comment: Если результат вас не устраивает, создайте составной индекс:
время, пара, тип.